# Getting invalid parameter when looping through .FullSeriesCollection if the Range has an empty cell

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I am setting a dynamic single column range, then looping through that Range to build a ColumnClustered graph.

If the Range has an empty cell looping through the `.FullSeriesCollection` throws an invalid parameter error. Error occurs at 
`With .FullSeriesCollection(I)`.

Is there any easy way around this? I would like to show that the empty cell exists, this is a time point, but does not exist for this particular parameter getting graphed.

Appreciate any help!

```
With Sheets(GSheet).ChartObjects.Add _
            (Left:=100, Width:=200, Top:=75, Height:=150)

  With .Chart

      .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
      'Set data source range.
      .SetSourceData Source:=MyRange, PlotBy:=xlRows

      For I = 1 To MyRange.Count                
          With .FullSeriesCollection(I)    
             ' Do Stuff   
          End With           
      Next I

  End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign `MyRange` only cells that contain a value.  One way would be to use the `Union` method.  Another way would be to use the `SpecialCells` method.  Here's an example using the `Union` method, assuming that the source data is located in the first sheet, and in A2:A10...

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim MyRange As Range

For Each rCell In Sheets(1).Range("A2:A10")
    If Len(rCell) > 0 Then
        If MyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set MyRange = rCell
        Else
            Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, rCell)
        End If
    End If
Next rCell
```

Also, you should test whether MyRange has been assigned any cells...

```
If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
    'Create your chart
    '
    '
Else
    MsgBox "No data found.", vbExclamation
End If
```

Hope this helps!